# Why is my code not echoing anything out?

Tags: php, mysql

My code wont echo out to me, yet I believe it should be working. I'm trying to have it tell me that if it finds a row in my database, to match it and tell me im logged in, or if it finds no rows, then to echo out that the combo is invalid. Regardless, its not echo'ing out a single thing? I'm very new to this, and I just can not seem to figure it out. Work your magic please guys?

Note: All of the databases referred to in the query do exist, and it is connected to that database as well.

Thanks!

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password'])) 
{
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password_hash = md5($password);

if (!empty($username)&&!empty($password)) 
{
    $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username' AND `password`='$password_hash'";
    if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) 
    {
        $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);
        if ($query_num_rows==0) 
        {
            echo 'Invalid username password combination';
        }
            else 
        {
            echo 'Ok.';
        }
    }
}
}

?>

<form action="<?php echo $current_file; ?>" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" class="login"> 
Password: <input type="password" name="password" class="login">
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Comment: Try with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on the top of the page.

Comment: You **really** need to learn from [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com) and use prepared statements!

Comment: Add more `echo`s into your code, every step of the way, to see where it stops. That will make it a lot easier to debug. Also, [sanitise](http://xkcd.com/327/) your [inputs](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: You have 2 `if` with no `else`, maybe they are returning `false`

Comment: Database connection is missing...

Answer (score 1):

You aren't connecting to a database.  You need to add something like this:

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
```

Comment: If this answered the question for you, please mark it as "answered". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of else without a respective else statement that prints something out. If one of this if condition is false you get no outpu. try:

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password'])) 
{
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];
   $password_hash = md5($password);

   if (!empty($username)&&!empty($password)) 
   {
      $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username' AND `password`='$password_hash'";
      if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) 
      {
          $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);
          if ($query_num_rows==0) 
          {
               echo 'Invalid username password combination';
          }
          else 
          {
             echo 'Ok.';
          }
      }
      else echo 'query exeution returned false';
   }
   else echo 'empty username or password';
}
else echo 'not isset username or pwd';
```

Finally if you get no output even with this else stataments then watch into the log if any fatal error appears and blocks the execution before any output is print!